# Converter estrutura para string

Tags: c

Como posso converter um inteiro para string? Exemplo: converter `int cod`  para `char cod[30]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>



struct Tipo_Lista{
    int cod;
    struct Tipo_Lista *Prox;
};

struct Tipo_Lista *Primeiro;
struct Tipo_Lista *Ultimo;

void FlVazia(){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = (struct Tipo_Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tipo_Lista));
    Primeiro = aux;
    Ultimo = Primeiro;
}

int Insere(int x){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = (struct Tipo_Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tipo_Lista));
    aux->cod = x;
    Ultimo->Prox = aux;
    Ultimo = Ultimo->Prox;
    aux->Prox = NULL;
}

void Imprime(){
    struct Tipo_Lista *aux;
    aux = Primeiro->Prox;
    while(aux !=NULL){
        printf("\n\nItem = %d", aux->cod);
        aux = aux->Prox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está querendo que o conteudo de um inteiro vire uma string?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem um inteiro e quer transformá-la em uma cadeia de caracteres, você pode usar a função *sprintf* que faz o contrário da *atoi*.

A função *sprintf*

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

cria uma string com o mesmo conteúdo a ser impresso se *format* fosse usado em *printf*, mas, ao invés de imprimir, o conteúdo é armazenado em um buffer apontado por *str*.

**O buffer apontado por *str* tem de ser obrigatoriamente grande o suficiente para armazenar a string resultante.**

Leia mais sobre essa função [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Ou seja, o que você quer fazer é:

```
int numero = 20180815;
char palavra[100];
sprintf(palavra, "%d", numero);
// Agora, palavra tem como conteudo "20180815".
```

Comment: Interessante, eu realmente nunca tinha visto essa função deve ter uma sscanf também né, mas tipo pra eu colocar isso nessa minha função Insere. fui tentar fazer algo e não deu certo tipo. int sprintf(char *x){